# pchart stroke function

Tags: php, png, pchart

The call to Stroke() function in pChart renders an Image. When I try to display this image on the browser, it shows something like the following instead of showing an image. How can I display the image instead of these wierd characters?

```
�PNG  ��� IHDR����������h����tRNS������7X}�� �IDATx���wt[Y~'���C
```

H�Q�(*�RV)TUW��v�}��cό�9�;g�xvv�;s��z����a�㝙 �v�cUu�*����L�,Q)f��/��@E�� ����
����.���{��W?"������P}�rW�������� !�����@�BB�����P�������T)$�������U !�����@�BB
�����P�X˲�]������(!������RH������B������*��������J!!������RH������
B������*��������Jaaz������*�+�������U !�����@�BB�����P�������T)$�������U !�����@�BB
�����P��!�����@�b˸������m����s��EA��0LE��^늧�2�

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are outputting the image directly from a call to a PHP script, such as `<img src="yourscript.php" />` then you're going to need to send the correct `Content-Type` header:

```
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($yourimage));
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

Note that any calls to **[header()](http://php.net/header)** must occur before output is started.